# Why is arglist of __init__ a tuple rather than a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a class as follows:

```py
class SMemberImpl():
    """docstring for SMemberImpl"""
    def __init__(self, *arglist):
        print(f"initializing SMemberImpl arglist={arglist} of type {type(arglist)}")
        super(SMemberImpl, self).__init__()
        self.arglist = arglist

    #... stuff omitted

class SMember(SMemberImpl):
    pass
```

When I create an instance of `SMember` by calling `SMember(1,2,3)` I see that the type of `arglist` is `tuple` rather than `list`.

Is this the expected behavior?  Or am I doing something wrong?  I'd rather `arglist` have type `list`, not `tuple`.

Comment: The `*args` format passed the positional arguments in a tuple by design. If you want to pass a list, explicitly pass a list instead.

Comment: Yes, it's expected: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=tuple#calls

Comment: @rdas, when you say I need to explicitly pass a list, doesn't that defeat the purpose of varargs functions?    Can I simply call `list` inside the `__init__` function?  `self.arglist = list(arglist)`

Comment: `args` will always be a tuple when used like that. You can make a new `list` by calling `arg_list = list(args)` before the place where you need a list.